# Allow specific User-Agent to specific file

Tags: nginx

I want to allow ONLY a specific User-Agent "Mozilla/4.0" to get some specific files on some host:

```
location ~* ^.+.(txt|doc).*?$ {
        if ($http_user_agent !~ ^Mozilla/4\.0$) {
                return 404;
        }
}
```

and doesn't seem to work, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Nobody can help in this matter?

Comment: Are you sure that user agent is `Mozilla/4.0`? There's no browsers with the string exact like your regexp.

Comment: I'm very sure about that because I set that User-Agent myself for testing: [28/Nov/2012:15:29:41 +0400] "POST /joomla/image.php HTTP/1.1" 200 150 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"

Comment: Then it's most likely that your request doesn't even reach your new `location`. Could you provide full config?